# using sed to insert whitespaces between a number and word

Tags: regex, bash, sed, whitespace

I have a series of files that uses fixed with delimiting, instead of comma separated delimiting. They all look like this:

```
2015/09/29 659027 RIH619 25 105.80IN921186
2015/09/29 659027 RIH619 25 105.80IN921186
2015/09/29 659027 RIH619 25 105.80IN921186
2015/09/29 659027 RIH619 25 105.80IN921186
```

I would like to replace all the spaces with commas. I have a piece of code that accomplish this:

```
sed -r 's/^\s+//;s/\s+/,/g'
```

After running the code I get this result:

```
2015/09/29,659027,RIH619,25,105.80IN921186
2015/09/29,659027,RIH619,25,105.80IN921186
2015/09/29,659027,RIH619,25,105.80IN921186
2015/09/29,659027,RIH619,25,105.80IN921186
```

My problem is the files I get doesn't have a space between the amount and the reference. My output needs to look like this:

```
2015/09/29,659027,RIH619,25,105.80,IN921186
2015/09/29,659027,RIH619,25,105.80,IN921186
2015/09/29,659027,RIH619,25,105.80,IN921186
2015/09/29,659027,RIH619,25,105.80,IN921186
```

What I tried is:

```
sed -r 's/^\s+//;s/\.\d\d\D+/\.\d\d,\D/;s/\s+/,/g'
```

But it didn't seem to do anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `tr` and `sed`

```
 tr ' ' ',' <file | sed -r 's/(\.[0-9]{2})/\1,/'
```

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me. I made a change to the code to replace a number of spaces following each other to be replaced by a single comma, not multiple ones :) `tr -s ' ' ',' <"${FILE[0]}" | sed -r 's/(\.[0-9]{2})/\1,/'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this single sed for both:

```
sed -r 's/[[:blank:]]+/,/g; s/([[:digit:]])([[:alpha:]])/\1,\2/g' file
2015/09/29,659027,RIH619,25,105.80,IN921186
2015/09/29,659027,RIH619,25,105.80,IN921186
2015/09/29,659027,RIH619,25,105.80,IN921186
2015/09/29,659027,RIH619,25,105.80,IN921186
```

- `([[:digit:]])` matches a digit and captures it in group#1
- `([[:alpha:]])` matches an alphabet and captures it in group#2
- `\1,\2` places a comma between 2 groups.

Comment: I would use `s/[[:alpha:]]+[[:digit:]]+$/,&/` for the last part, to the same effect.

Comment: @anubhava is there any advantage to using `[[:digit:]]` over `[0-9]`

Comment: They both should behave same in this context but using POSIX classes is considered a better practice.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` has fixed field width support that is good for this sort of thing:

```
$ echo "2015/09/29 659027 RIH619 25 105.80IN921186" | 
    awk 'BEGIN { FIELDWIDTHS="10 1 6 1 6 1 2 1 6 8"; OFS="," }{ print $1,$3,$5,$7,$9,$10 }'
2015/09/29,659027,RIH619,25,105.80,IN921186
```